# Tab's in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have Makefile that contains tabified line `echo $(foo)` and untabified line `ifneq (,$(findstring i, $(MAKEFLAGS)))`:

```
bar =
foo = $(bar)

all:
    echo $(foo)
ifneq (,$(findstring i, $(MAKEFLAGS)))
    echo "i was passed to MAKEFLAGS"
endif
```

If I untabify `echo $(foo)` I got error:

```
Makefile:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Why some lines should be tabified while other ones - not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, that's the syntax makefiles use.  Why do you have to indent the body of methods in Python?  Because that's the syntax.

Makefiles consist of two different "languages" in the same file.  Lines that are not indented by TAB are makefile format.  Lines that are indented by TAB are shell scripts.  Make uses TAB to differentiate the two.

See [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Introduction.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

> Why some lines should be tabified while other ones - not?

Every line of each recipe must begin with a tab.  Every line that is *not* part of a recipe should not begin with a tab.  The crux of the issue is that in the example makefile, your `ifneq` and `endif` directives are not part of a recipe.  They are processed by `make`, during makefile parsing, not passed to a shell when the recipe is run.  In some ways, this is the same kind of distinction as between C preprocessing directives and the surrounding source code.